# Git: If I push a new branch to origin, how to make it tracking automatically

Tags: git

I created a new local branch and pushed it with

```
git push origin my-branch
```

How can I automatically set up my local branch to tag the just created remote branch?

Or do I always need

```
git branch --set-upstream my-branch  origin/my-branch
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `git push -u origin my-branch`. This will set-up everything for argument-less push/pull.